nextjs build error failing Error: Cannot find module
Node.js v20.11.1
   Collecting page data  ...bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?)
   Collecting page data  .
node:internal/event_target:1100
  process.nextTick(() => { throw err; });
                           ^
Error: Cannot find module 'E:\hackthon\reclaim\.next\server\app\api\actions\reclaim\lib\worker.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at MessagePort.<anonymous> (node:internal/main/worker_thread:186:26)
    at [nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (node:internal/event_target:826:20)
    at exports.emitMessage (node:internal/per_context/messageport:23:28)
Emitted 'error' event on Worker instance at:
    at [kOnErrorMessage] (node:internal/worker:326:10)
    at [kOnMessage] (node:internal/worker:337:37)
    at MessagePort.<anonymous> (node:internal/worker:232:57)
    at [nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (node:internal/event_target:826:20)
    at exports.emitMessage (node:internal/per_context/messageport:23:28)
    at [kOnExit] (node:internal/worker:304:5)
    at Worker.<computed>.onexit (node:internal/worker:229:20) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v20.11.1

> Build error occurred
Error: Jest worker encountered 4 child process exceptions, exceeding retry limit
    at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (E:\hackthon\reclaim\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\jest-worker\index.js:1:11580)
    at ChildProcessWorker._onExit (E:\hackthon\reclaim\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\jest-worker\index.js:1:12545)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:294:12) {
  type: 'WorkerError'
}

I just need to get rid of this errors and start the server. I am getting some errors in a route but they are of no significance but the build is failing due to them. How do i bypass this
